# Adding if else statement to function to repeat function if output is character (0)

Tags: r, function, if-statement, character

I have created a function that returns output from software. This function will be looped with new input every time, by being integrated into a for loop. However, the software is very temperamental and will often return 'character(0)'. If the function is manually repeated multiple times it will hit the intended output.

To resolve this I want to automate this process with an if else statement within the loop, so that if the output would be 'character(0)' the function runs again. The function is intended to return the variable 'all_evaluations', which is a list of 4 strings.

I have added this if else statement at the end of the function:

```
stockfish_function <- function(move){
...
if (is.null(all_evaluations)){ ... } else {
    return(all_evaluations)
  }
}
```

Whereby '...' represents the code for the function and then the code function pasted back again into the if statement.

However, function still returns 'character(0)' on many inputs.

For the sake of context this is the complete function:

```
stockfish_function <- function(move){
  
  ### stockfish commands ###
  ##initiate
  stockfish$write_input('uci\n')
  
  ##input individual moves
  stockfish$write_input(paste0('position startpos moves ',move,'\n'))
  
  ##make that move
  stockfish$write_input('go movetime 100\n') 
  
  ##evaluate it
  stockfish$write_input('eval\n') 
  
  ##read output
  stockfish_response <- stockfish$read_output_lines() 
  
  
  ### extract output with regex ###              
  #this assigns lines which contain evaluation to variables
  classical_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'Classical evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
  nnue_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'NNUE evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
  final_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'Final evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
  best_move <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'bestmove.+ponder.+')
  
  #this ensures only the final notation of each is returned
  classical_evaluation <- head(classical_evaluation[complete.cases(classical_evaluation), ], 1)
  nnue_evaluation <- head(nnue_evaluation[complete.cases(nnue_evaluation), ], 1)
  final_evaluation <- head(final_evaluation[complete.cases(final_evaluation), ], 1)
  best_move <- head(best_move[complete.cases(best_move), ], 1)
  
  #appends each variable to a list
  all_evaluations <- append(classical_evaluation, nnue_evaluation)
  all_evaluations <- append(all_evaluations, final_evaluation)
  all_evaluations <- append(all_evaluations, best_move)
  
  #this if statement reruns the code 
  if (is.null(all_evaluations)){
    
    ### stockfish commands ###
    ##initiate
    stockfish$write_input('uci\n')
    
    ##input individual moves
    stockfish$write_input(paste0('position startpos moves ',move,'\n'))
    
    ##make that move
    stockfish$write_input('go movetime 100\n') 
    
    ##evaluate it
    stockfish$write_input('eval\n') 
    
    ##read output
    stockfish_response <- stockfish$read_output_lines() 
    
    
    ### extract output with regex ###              
    #this assigns lines which contain evaluation to variables
    classical_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'Classical evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
    nnue_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'NNUE evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
    final_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'Final evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
    best_move <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'bestmove.+ponder.+')
    
    #this ensures only the final notation of each is returned
    classical_evaluation <- head(classical_evaluation[complete.cases(classical_evaluation), ], 1)
    nnue_evaluation <- head(nnue_evaluation[complete.cases(nnue_evaluation), ], 1)
    final_evaluation <- head(final_evaluation[complete.cases(final_evaluation), ], 1)
    best_move <- head(best_move[complete.cases(best_move), ], 1)
    
    #appends each variable to a list
    all_evaluations <- append(classical_evaluation, nnue_evaluation)
    all_evaluations <- append(all_evaluations, final_evaluation)
    all_evaluations <- append(all_evaluations, best_move)
    
  } else {
    #returns evaluations
    return(all_evaluations)
  }
  
}
```

Comment: you do not need the `== TRUE` as `is.null()` already returns a TRUE/FALSE statement depending on the value...    

and as we dont know either your `if()` statement or your input data it is not possible to say why/how it returns `NA`

Answer (score 0):

What your example code seems to do, is check *only once* if all_evaluations is NULL, and if so it will attempt *only once more* to run the copy-pasted code. But of course, if the external program fails again that second try, your function still returns erroneous values.

What we need is to execute the external function over and over again, until it finally works. Or perhaps we can add a `max-tries` parameter to give up after a certain amount of attempts.

It seems the error in the external program can already be detected in the output of `stockfish$read_output_lines()`, so I suggest to check its output as soon as possible, and only repeat that part instead of the entire code after it as well.

You mentioned that the erroneous output is `character(0)`. I don't know what the correct output would look like, but I will test if the output is different from `character(0)` by looking at the length; if it has *any* length other than 0, we know it was successful and we continue to the rest of the function:

```
  # infinite repeat
  repeat {
    stockfish$write_input('uci\n')
    stockfish$write_input(paste0('position startpos moves ',move,'\n'))
    stockfish$write_input('go movetime 100\n') 
    stockfish$write_input('eval\n') 
    stockfish_response <- stockfish$read_output_lines()
    
    # break the infinite repeat if we have the correct result
    if(length(stockfish_response)) break;
  }
```

*(I have removed your comments in this block, for legibility)*

###### Adding "maximum tries"

We can add a little counter to the `repeat` statement, to quit after too many attempts. This will prevent the program to keep running forever if stockfish_response keeps failing.

You could also put a `return()` instead of a `stop()`.

```
  # infinite repeat
  attempt <- 0
  repeat {
    stockfish$write_input('uci\n')
    stockfish$write_input(paste0('position startpos moves ',move,'\n'))
    stockfish$write_input('go movetime 100\n') 
    stockfish$write_input('eval\n') 
    stockfish_response <- stockfish$read_output_lines()
    
    # break the infinite repeat if we have the correct result
    if(length(stockfish_response)) break;
    
    # quit if we have too many tries
    attempt <- attempt + 1
    if(attempt > 10) stop("No valid stockfish_response after 10 tries")
  }
```

###### Complete function

The complete function (with some of your comments removed) would look like this:

```
stockfish_function <- function(move){
  
  # infinite repeat
  repeat {
    stockfish$write_input('uci\n')
    stockfish$write_input(paste0('position startpos moves ',move,'\n'))
    stockfish$write_input('go movetime 100\n') 
    stockfish$write_input('eval\n') 
    stockfish_response <- stockfish$read_output_lines()
    
    # break the infinite repeat if we have the correct result
    if(length(stockfish_response)) break;
  }
  
  ### extract output with regex ###              
  #this assigns lines which contain evaluation to variables
  classical_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'Classical evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
  nnue_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'NNUE evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
  final_evaluation <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'Final evaluation.+?\\(white side\\)')
  best_move <- str_match(stockfish_response, 'bestmove.+ponder.+')
  
  #this ensures only the final notation of each is returned
  classical_evaluation <- head(classical_evaluation[complete.cases(classical_evaluation), ], 1)
  nnue_evaluation <- head(nnue_evaluation[complete.cases(nnue_evaluation), ], 1)
  final_evaluation <- head(final_evaluation[complete.cases(final_evaluation), ], 1)
  best_move <- head(best_move[complete.cases(best_move), ], 1)
  
  #appends each variable to a list
  all_evaluations <- append(classical_evaluation, nnue_evaluation)
  all_evaluations <- append(all_evaluations, final_evaluation)
  all_evaluations <- append(all_evaluations, best_move)
  
  #returns evaluations
  return(all_evaluations)
  
}
```